# How to set the substitution character for encoding into ISO-8859-1

Tags: perl, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

The documentation for the Encode module says this about handling malformed characters while encoding:

> CHECK = Encode::FB_DEFAULT ( == 0)
>
> > If *CHECK* is 0, encoding and decoding replace any malformed character with a *substitution character*.  When you
> >              encode, *SUBCHAR* is used.

How can I specify, or at least query, what the substitution characters is for a particular encoding. I'm interested in `iso-8859-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, but you can use a callback to achieve the same effect.

```
$ perl -MEncode -E'say encode("iso-8859-1", "ab\x{2660}d\x{E9}f")' \
   | iconv -f iso-8859-1
ab?déf

$ perl -MEncode -E'say encode("iso-8859-1", "ab\x{2660}d\x{E9}f", sub { "*" })' \
   | iconv -f iso-8859-1
ab*déf
```

Comment: (The `iconv -f iso-8859-1` is because I have a UTF-8 terminal)